# TBB parallel_for: why Body::operator() argument is not const?

Tags: c++, tbb

This [page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506153) from the Intel TBB Developer Reference lists requirements for the `parallel_for` template parameter `Body`, among them this one:

```
void Body::operator()( Range& range ) const
```

Why is the `Range` argument passed to the `operator()` without `const`? It'd be good to see an example where it's necessary and/or useful.

Comment: I believe it just happens to be so due to historical reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we were just trying to keep the requirements as minimal as possible, and not trying to guess what creative uses people might come up with.  But it would seem now that `const` usage is the only use case in practice.  The most creative use of `parallel_for` I came up with was the one in `tbb::parallel_sort`, and even that one takes a const Range.